# Android soft keyboard to support time in both decimal and hh:mm formats

Tags: android

My Android app has an EditText field where the user can enter elapsed time as either a decimal (e.g. "1.5") or hours and minutes (e.g. "1:30"). The issue I'm having is displaying a soft keyboard that allows entry of 0..9, period, and colon.

The default keyboard has the characters I need but the user has to always first hit the Sym key to enter anything useful, which isn't very efficient.

In the EditText if I instead try inputType="numberDecimal", or inputType="time", or inputType="datetime", etc., I get some combination of digits, periods, and colons, but not all on the same soft keyboard. I've tested this on a few different Samsung Galaxy devices.

Is there a soft keyboard I can use that contains the characters I need, or is there a way to customize which characters display on a particular soft keyboard? A bonus would be to also allow commas for Euro-style decimals (e.g. "1,5").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resurrecting an old post here, but I ran into a similar issue today where I need both the decimal and colon to be selectable without showing the full keyboard. For the `EditText`, you can use the following attributes:

```
android:inputType="time"
```

On my device's stock keyboard, there are still a couple extra inputs (dash and space), but it's close enough to what I need without creating a custom keyboard. To restrict the undesired inputs, you can specify in the EditText inputs are acceptable:

```
android:digits="0123456789:."
```

Comment: Well, in the past 3.5 years we've ported the app to React Native, but this would've been exactly what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

> In the EditText if I instead try inputType="numberDecimal", or inputType="time", or inputType="datetime", etc., I get some combination of digits, periods, and colons, but not all on the same soft keyboard.

`inputType` is a hint. There are hundreds, perhaps thousands, of input method editor implementations for Android, both pre-installed and installed by users. None have to pay any attention to `inputType`. Those that do can do what they want in response to it.

> Is there a soft keyboard I can use that contains the characters I need

There is no `inputType` that corresponds to what you want, and there is no requirement for any input method editor to pay attention to it.

> is there a way to customize which characters display on a particular soft keyboard?

No.

Comment: Sounds like the only answer then is to create my own soft keyboard for the app...

Comment: @Roger: If by "soft keyboard", you mean an input method editor, those are not for an app, but for the whole device. You are certainly welcome to create your own set of buttons or something. Off the cuff, I would simply not use an `EditText`, but instead use something else to collect the duration (e.g., two `NumberPicker` widgets for hours and minutes).